# How can I track cases when a pointer from a "new" expression is passed to dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, new-operator, smart-pointers

Recently I found the following while reviewing some old code:

```
auto_ptr<DerivedClass> pointer = dynamic_cast<CBase*>( new CDerived() );
```

aside from the fact that this code is meaningless in valid cases (in valid cases `class Derived` is derived from `class Base` and no `dynamic_cast` is necessary) there's a problem with object ownership. If for whatever reason `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer the `auto_ptr` will not be bound to the created object and the object will be leaked.

Is there some technique to help prevent such errors like making a compiler issue a warning or anything like that?

Comment: Something like grep? Or do you need a more advanced way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of all your `dynamic_cast`s.

All of them.

Then no tracking will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find anything already available you can also add your own [rule](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page#Documents_and_articles) to [cpp check](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/)